# Do heavier java libraries cause Google App Engine to take longer in starting instances?

Tags: google-app-engine

Do heavier java libraries cause Google App Engine to take longer in starting instances?

Even if the libary isn't used at all until later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is yes.  I tested it by doing a simple hello world servlet.  It averaged about 2 seconds to load.  Then I added a bunch of libraries that I didn't even use.  Then it averaged about 4 seconds to load.

Though it could just be that the server was running slower while I did my second test. I only did a few tests for each case.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, while loading an instance of an application for the first time, the app engine takes a fixed minimum amount of time for all application (for initializing the jvm and what not).
So I don't think having a few extra libraries will affect much, may be a few dozen milliseconds at most.
For google's take on the matter, read this post "[Request performance in Java](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/12/request-performance-in-java.html)"

Answer (score 0):

Yes. One reason is because the app is compiled on each initial load, so if the app has any reference to libraries it'll have to load them to perform compile-time checks. You can reduce this by enabling precompilation:
http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/12/request-performance-in-java.html